# Will Google Play Services work on Yun OS phone?

Tags: google-play-services

I have [this](http://www.i3shouji.com/zhinengji/p2544.html) Chinese Phone which is a Yun OS, I've tried all different types (Architecture, Android Version, Screen DPI) of Google Play Services from [APKmirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-8-7-03-release/) site but all goes "Unfortunately, Google Play Services has stopped".

My phone is also not rooted. Tried many root apps (kingroot, kingo, etc.) mobile/pc but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR answer: It won't work.

Google Play Services relies on several apps and libraries to reside in a few different system directories, you can't just "install" Google Play Services, you need to flash them into your system with a 3rd party recovery like [TWRP](https://twrp.me/) or CWM Recovery. The gapps are available from [OpenGapps](http://opengapps.org/) and other sources.

Although a little research tells me that Yun OS is NOT Android, although it is based on AOSP.

> According to Google, Aliyun (YuOS) is a forked but incompatible version of its open-source Android operating system.
>
> Yun OS incorporates its own virtual machine, which is different from Android's Dalvik virtual machine.

- [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yun_OS#Relations_with_Android)

And some searching also show very few, if any, people who have gotten the Google Play services to work, probably the biggest reason is YunOS uses a unique VM that is not Dalvik or ART, therefore it will not work.